# Can someone please explain the need of quotes in the following text?

Tags: british-english

I saw this as a slogan in an episode of *Drop the Dead Donkey* and just wanted to know why were quotes needed on the word **synergise**:

> Let nowness "synergise" with excellence.

I think it makes sense to take the quote off.

Comment: They are called [scare quotes](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69547/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-scare-quotes).

Comment: They could profitably be dropped. But then, in most circumstances, so could the whole sentence.

Comment: Edwin - hee hee :)

Comment: sa1 - they idicate sarcasm -- often like "air quotes" (google up a video if you don't know what those are)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Scare quotes or shudder quotes are quotation marks placed around a word or phrase to imply that it may not signify its apparent meaning or that it is not necessarily the way the quoting person would express its concept.
>   -- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes)

You could get rid of them if you wanted. What the author is saying is it "synergise"s with excellence, but are trying to imply a sarcastic tone.

The phrase is similar to "accelerate success" and "accentuate choice" - marketing speak, and pretty meaningless.

Comment: exactly - in fact you could put quotes round "nowness" as well, they are both management-speak, i.e. pretty meaningless!