# Whats a word for a person that thinks they’re your buddy, but they are not

Tags: single-word-requests

Doing a simple school project. Basically, a person who is willing to be your friend but is not reciprocated by you.

Any category would great. It's to be on the derogatory side of the spectrum

> Unfortunately, I found my "buddy" Don who was eager like usual to begin a conversation.

(Do apologize if I'm missing something here. First time posting)

Thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. Please click through to the tag info for [tag:single-word-requests]. There is a checklist of things you should include in your question. You can use the [edit] link to revise your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unfortunately, I found my "buddy" Don who was eager like usual…

Your solution of using [scare quotes](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/69552/44619) is actually very good and despite what President Trump's Tweets may tell us, used correctly.  Scare quotes say that a term is being used (very) loosely, or incorrectly, or inappropriately.

Answer (score 1):

If the person keeps showing up and you can't seem to get rid of them, they could be a

**hanger-on** *n.* (plural hangers-on)
*a person who associates with another person or a group in a sycophantic manner or for the purpose of gaining some personal advantage*

If the person does so by imitating you, then they could be a a

**wannabe** *n.*
*a person who tries to be like someone else or to fit in with a particular group of people: a star-struck wannabe.*

If their defining characteristic is to always agree with you or say how right you are, they could be a

**sycophant** *n.*
*a person who acts obsequiously toward someone important in order to gain advantage*.

Comment: The OP is asking for a noun, so the adjective "unctuous" is not strictly a correct answer, but "unctuous sycophant" is a great characterization of a certain kind of person.

Answer (score 0):

I would call Don an  'imposer'. 
This noun is derived from the verb 'to impose'.
According to Merriam-Webster Dictionary:
IMPOSE 
: to force into the company or on the attention of another.